# Fluent API with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to develop a fluent api in TypeScript, which I would like to use as follows:

```js
export interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

new Builder<Person>()
    .func1("stringArg1")
    .func2("firstName")
    .func3("stringArg2");
```

`func2` may only accept names of properties that actually occur in the specified interface (here: `Person`).
Furthermore, `func2` shall only be available at the return value of `func1` and `func3` only at the return value of `func2`. The sequence of function calls must be observed in any case.
The class `Builder` must be able to evaluate the specified values at any time (`stringArg1`, `firstName` and `stringArg2`).

I would be very grateful for advices and help.

Comment: What does "The class `Builder` must be able to evaluate the specified values at any time" mean?  And what type or shape or functionality will the return value of `func3()` have?

Comment: There's plenty of prior art for this.  https://www.google.com/search?q=typescript+fluent+api

Comment: [This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgBTQGcIk4BvAWACg4650EoiYA5TAW2AC44WpkAcwDcNenAA2mFuy69+Q0dQC+NGtilEicAEIBXBBIAmaADwAVAHwUx9dHqTYAjHAC8cABTonmKIPkwAkiCAJRu1h5UtOJ2DtgATLxe8b7+cADWwACeEOhw5mGuEVExpQxxAMxJ6BWpAUGh4Z4lZa0A9G18EFwwABZCcL1owAD8tq10yiHjMVMzcypq1EjAAO66BsZmhMyklh7T0XQAdPaOTh4ARArBAIJ+TpeH4qdx8VeMzGycwE8zr44KlcboJ7oJ4k9hEA) is one possible interpretation of what you're asking for; if it doesn't work for you I think you might want to elaborate on the use case.

Comment: @jcalz: Thank you very much. This sounds like a possible solution.

Comment: @RobertHarvey your link lists this question on the top result.

Comment: @VLAZ: It didn't when I originally posted it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Probably. But that's always a problem when there is some question and a suggestion to "google it". I got to this page after a web search. Only to find your suggestion to make a web search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible implementation of what you're asking for could be something like this:

```
class Builder<T> {
    func1 = (f1arg: string) => ({
        func2: (f2arg: keyof T) => ({
            func3: (f3arg: string) => ({
                // something here?
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Here though we are not maintaining a single class instance of `Builder`. Once you call `func1()`, you get a new object with a `func2` property.  When you're all done, `func3()` can return whatever you'd like (and it has access to the arguments due to being closed over them), including an instance of `Builder` if you want.  Depending on what you're looking for, this might work.

---

The more normal case of a `Builder` class is something that, after each method, returns the same instance of that class.  That's easy enough to write if you don't have restrictions on what methods can be called when.  If you do have such restrictions, you can tell the compiler this, but it's a bit complicated looking.  Here's one possible way to do it:

```
type Builder0<T> = Omit<_Builder<T>, "func2" | "func3">;
type Builder1<T> = Omit<_Builder<T>, "func1" | "func3">;
type Builder2<T> = Omit<_Builder<T>, "func1" | "func2">;
type Builder<T> = Omit<_Builder<T>, "func1" | "func2" | "func3">;
class _Builder<T> {
    f1arg?: string;
    f2arg?: keyof T;
    f3arg?: string;
    func1(f1arg: string): Builder1<T> {
        this.f1arg = f1arg;
        return this;
    }
    func2(f2arg: keyof T): Builder2<T> {
        this.f2arg = f2arg;
        return this;
    }
    func3(f3arg: string): Builder<T> {
        this.f3arg = f3arg;
        return this;
    }
}
const Builder: new <T>() => Builder0<T> = _Builder;
```

In this case, each method returns `this`, and at runtime it's just a "normal"-ish fluent interface.  But the compiler will see `new Builder<Person>()` as something that produces not a `Builder<Person>`, but a `Builder0<Person>`, which (if you look at the type), is the same as a builder but it uses [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to prevent TS code from accessing its `func2` or `func3` method.  If you call `func1()`, it returns a `Builder1<Person>`, which prevents TS codefrom accessing its `func1` or `func3` methods.  So when you call `func1()` followed by `func2()` followed by `func3()` the compiler takes a `Builder0` and returns a `Builder1` which returns a `Builder2` which finally returns a `Builder`, which omits all those methods.

You can verify that it also enforces those order restrictions while maintaining the return value as the same class instance the whole time.

---

Hopefully one of those approaches gives you some ideas.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEARAlgMwwFwPICMArKJAbwFgAoJGpCADxgHsAnbJNYbCFjBZAAo8oTYGSq1JSDGhZRsAOXAQAXEnktOAcwDcEqTQA2IeUshqN2vdVoBfKvprxjUEgCEArmkMATHgB4AFQA+cRsDDA9geABGJABeJAAKDBiQFi0LbE1gLQBKBNCkinCDWkjogCY1FMr0zKQAawgATyYMJECC+KKSsv7pKPgAZhqMYfqsnPzC5L6BhYB6RfUmSGwAC20kDZ4IAH5HBbs8o-7bU9LJC6P7SiPgCAB3JE9vPxZ-ITlRYKTL-oAOgqsSSACJLLkAIIZGJggFlYFDSrgmRyRTKeFnWhI6LDcGQrQwrSVeHWO4OSigSCwfhIADK2kMEAAwi4SPMaAxmGwOFweHxEEhviIxJypGjTMoplZsUYTBjzOpsrLShTStgWjBkG9fDwAAxBUKJXBgNDYfwAfV1HyNABokGCQaSkAAfR0g4Zg4I6JBHTXa15ePUsGJGhJIU3mq02gIhB1OoZwt0eoZen3+rU64MfSrhk1mi3WnNx4IJkHJ92Jqre6ySAPZ96liNRouxz7x1PRStd+Auque2tHZwmEjFpsd0LiySper7GW5OtlDB1DLzpqtdqdJcRCZrhe6OWDbspNIZA95NTtsMhMLHJCbNBQYFnrQR2cZHcDFgQbAeFhiI+UBftcR7OrUkwbm0HRdFeJYsHmt7TmUQHAqub6JCu9QgWUP5-gBD5bMBR53P0nopHuDSEpeQYTuGyEGKh4z1O+lE4QYeH-oBRHsUgpF2MOojyLRIZqI8LxGv8sztoat6JOOIbWJSkjwEJ7D4BG4kibaIq-P8R64qCEIqtCsJYlcOLgU6shSpA5lAuRxnTMSpJ5Ep9yULYQA)

Comment: This is also a very nice solution. Thanks for that! I'll take a closer look at it tomorrow. Today I won't have the chance to do it anymore, because I still have to cook :-)

Comment: I just tried your solution and it works very well! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again for your help and the detailed explanation. Many thanks also to all the others who helped me!

Comment: This is a great implementation and explanation. I'm trying to build something like this where multiple functions are included/omitted based on the type of argument, is there a way to "chain" these omissions, rather than create a type for each combination of functions? Maybe this is for a separate question

Answer (score 5):

I don't know exactly what are you trying to achieve but here you go an example of a fluent API

```
export interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

class Builder<T> {
  private func1Value?: string;
  private func2Value?: keyof T;
  private func3Value?: string;

  func1(arg: string): this {
    this.func1Value = arg;

    return this;
  }

  func2(key: keyof T): this {
    this.func2Value = key;

    return this;
  }

  func3(arg: string): this {
    this.func3Value = arg;

    return this;
  }
}

new Builder<Person>().func1('stringArg1').func2('firstName').func3('stringArg2');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Apparently, it's easier than I thought.

Comment: @Felix this answer doesn't stop you from calling `func2` before `func1`.  Is that a requirement?

Comment: @jcalz: Yes, it is more or less a requirement. I read your last answer and I think I will implement it as you suggested.