# Class method return type based on type of parameter

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I have a function that accepts anything as param, but if it receives a `function` (with prototype) **it should return an instance** of that function (or class, since they are functions).
If not, it may look anything asigned to that key inside a Map and return it.

The super simplified code would look something like ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAwuaAnArsKBDARgGwFMYBeGACgDMwAuGbMATwEpSA%20GKRgB0JEpjVSJMgHJK6MFjjhRMAGTyYo7qhBR1PQnLhhBYANwAoI8HzYIEGAEEwcALbZ8MAN5GYMMNnuE6aXQDmMAA%20MJIAJoSUuoTh7jCgkFAYWCCo5F4%20APx%20yYHMbh4eUAAWCAB0mcRkVcYeAL5GjaYosBCEqABucMDVnoQA7hRmFlYAyh3dva5GAJCO3KT9QwCy2NzkzCYe7VDkANaEjHQMjAA0MJ1O6L70TEuHLDNFMKiEUOioeqUVC%20W7ByOFyu%20BuWwa8XiAXeAB4ACpsQHHVzLCjMOhwmD1dEwTGFGCzRLQXEgABKhAgIHwnT6Pwg5T%200L2j2YdQJcAE5AQyCSKRwBEI5DhZIpVJpzFY%20I8szeHy%20qOF5Mp1MFrPiEJe6te70%20ekVopVbMa2JM7S6PUI-3e5FsDicarNU0tANEuBAuFEFzAgxsdkc%20HIogAQu7RBKTETYNDvagerb-UtHRbykybX77S0kjA3bhE5Nk6nXaHWAB6Es2VABdA%20MCwficLTKfxgAI6KxgdT0SxwAJeAWcEAwbjYVDed4dGD1ri8ZTeoabdhhMD7DsDMCiCMoKmW-AgALkaMdOPp5y6aAMXr1%20MZonb8q7-c5%20BJC98ATX-BbIA)):

```
// Go check service.get() method
const isConstructable = (fn: any) => typeof fn === 'function' && 'prototype' in fn;

class Animal {
  name: string | undefined
  constructor(name?: string){
    this.name = name;
  }
}

const service = new (class Service {
  map = new Map()

  set(key: any, value: any = key) {
    return this.map.set(key, value)
  }
  
  get<T>(key: { new (): T }): T {
    const ToResolve = this.map.get(key);
    if (isConstructable(ToResolve)) {
        return new ToResolve();
    }
    
    return ToResolve;
  }
})

service.set('bob', new Animal('Bob'))
service.set(Animal);

const genericAnimal = service.get(Animal)
const bob = service.get('bob') // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => unknown'

console.log(genericAnimal instanceof Animal)
console.log(bob instanceof Animal)
```

I was reading [Using Class Types in Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics) and found this code

```
function create<T>(c: { new (): T }): T {
  return new c();
}
```

It works well, but I need `get(key)` to not accept only constructables, but also any primitive accepted by `Map`, like:

```
const jane = {} // object reference, since TS won't let me use symbols
service.set(jane, class Jane extends Animal {
  constructor() {
    super('Jane')
  }
})
console.log(service.get(jane).name === 'Jane')
```

This way I'm getting compilation errors like `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => unknown'`

Also tried with: `get<T>(key: T): T extends Function ? T : unknown` which obviously doesn't work, but feels so close :(

Do I have to create a specific type for the `key` param? Define overloads? How?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain "TS won't let me use symbols"?  `const jane = Symbol("jane");"` works, right?  What is the issue?

Comment: Also, in that example, `service.get(jane)` would return a value of type `unknown` in your desired solution, right? So you couldn't write `service.get(jane).name` because `unknown` doesn't have a `name` property.  So what are you really looking for?

Comment: @jcalz that's not the main problem though. I'm looking for the proper "typing" for `service.get()`. I'm fine with `get("bob")` returning unknown as long as TS doesn't complains `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => unknown'`, AND `service.get(Animal)` returns an Animal.

Comment: The thing with Symbol is another story, I should not have mentioned it. Let's stick with the Function and String parameters just for mental health :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your signature for `get` is pretty close.  If you want to use conditional types, you can write it this way:

```
  get<T>(key: T): T extends new () => infer I ? I : unknown;
  get(key: any) {
    const ToResolve = this.map.get(key);
    if (isConstructable(ToResolve)) {
      return new ToResolve();
    }
    return ToResolve;
  }
```

In this case, if the type `T` corresponds to a zero-arg constructor, the return type will be the instance type of that constructor. Otherwise the return type is `unknown`.  Note that the compiler cannot verify that the implementation corresponds to that call signature (see [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for more info), so I'm using a single-call signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) whose implementation is more loosely typed.  This compiles fine, but the caveat is that it's your responsibility to make sure that the implementation conforms to the call signature.

---

This works as desired for your first set of example uses:

```
const genericAnimal = service.get(Animal) // Animal
const bob = service.get('bob') // unknown
```

but of course the `set()` method is so loosely typed that there's no guarantee that it will be used properly.

```
service.set(Animal, 1234); // no error? oops.
```

I'd suggest changing the `set()` method to mirror what's going on in the `get()` method:

```
  set<T>(
    key: T, 
    ...args: T extends new () => infer I ? [value?: I] : 
      [value: unknown]
  ): void;
  set(key: any, value?: any) {
    this.map.set(key, typeof value === "undefined" ? key : value);
  }
```

That signature might look scary, but basically it's saying that if `key` is a constructor function then you are allowed to either call `set()` with either zero or one additional argument (an argument tuple of type `[value?: I]` where `I` is the class instance type), but if `key` is not a constructor function then you have to call `set()` with an additional argument (an argument tuple of type `[value: unknown]`.

And then you'll get compiler errors if someone tries to pass something weird in with a constructor:

```
service.set(Animal, 1234); // error!
service.set(Animal); // okay
service.set('bob', new Animal('Bob')) // okay
```

---

Finally, I'm really not sure what to do about tracking the types of the values put in for non-constructor keys.  The compiler treats those as `unknown`, meaning if you set it and get it you have probably lost information:

```
service.set("string", "hello");
console.log(service.get("string").toUpperCase()); // error at compile time
// but HELLO at runtime
```

You'll either need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards) to deal with that:

```
const str = service.get("string") as string; // I'm telling the compiler it's a string
console.log(str.toUpperCase()); // works now

const str2 = service.get("string");
console.log(
  typeof str2 === "string" ? str2.toUpperCase() : "NOT A STRING"
); // I'm testing
```

There are possibly other ways to track the types using [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) or a [fluent API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63288162/fluent-api-with-typescript), but that seems to be outside the scope of the question.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAwuaAnArsKBDARgGwFMYBeGACgDMwAuGbMATwEpSA+GKRgB0JEpjVSJMgHJK6MFjjhRMAGTyYo7qhBR1PQnLhhBYANwAoI8HzYIEGAEEwcALbZ8MAN5GYMMNnuE6aXQDmMAA+MJIAJoSUuoTh7jCgkFAYWCCo5F4+APx+yYGsbh4eUAAWCAB0mcRkVQYw8QC+Rk2mKLAQhKgAbnDA1Z6EAO4UZhZWAMqdPX2u8Y7cpAPDALLY3OTMJh4dUAA8ACps5ADWhIx0+wA0MOW32KgBEBcwhAAeUIRg4VZgQxSsJA4ukonRgAEkYFkYABtLpOdCEHLggC6MDosPhvjCYGOYBAgzAyOYdC6IDg4WM20IUBOZzoDEY1zh+ARSIZBXixTKEHK83KO1pjM4Wn4MGZCOEZAARBEojFwlLITBTow0WLMcxKTAWh4AtSDkcVRdiTB9i93p9vkt-ux4GAQahwUqIXRJLj8YZ4nqaUb6EwOUUEm1TSAAEqECAgfBdfqlCp872CzWc+ACcgIZBJFI4AiEcj7MMRqMx5gBwMwVDU9CoPS-YYF8OR6N55OBpqBytQat6BtF5tapoNTZGDrdXqEfnU8i2BxOa4ARgATABmAAsmpgAHpNy9UGpUABCEdTceTmkzxz4ZOj6YTgWiXAgXCia51mx2S-kUQAISfolLJiJNAMB6r8qC9BeTiLDep6JpBV5bju8H1EBsCPrg0Enn05SJg+f6sNu2LugSgEoFGE74CAATkKBnQQR+UG6NADB9KK8GbEB5HlJR1HoXazFSHwAjsSYMHYQKUr+GAARStcUolIQ+CUVKyacUQ3FUeQYkTomkl5NJKnlBoACq3C8KgiAWC2G6EQAEgAogAMo5ADy9CwBgYBQA4xC4OgsCdPu7lBvY3BwEQnA+aRSQwGgmFjthulSTJrAWLF+kBHUhFgqI9icIp+CBJwCkhWFRCOnAUCiFY2DpeB0mtJAXE8VpyRGSApnmZZHQbDZO6DGkxw-Pi0XAWgi7xbeOFTnp9UpcYakUZpXC8KK42SjAs2BIqULje1nWdN1LZqlKAByLlmtYMDjPsoZgqdADiKlZTuOV5R80CBEYQAA)

Comment: Such a fantastic response! It makes more sense when I read some of the terms you've used to explain it. Let me test the code and I'll get back to you soon!